# How do rsync entire Docker dev environment and run in paralell

Tags: docker, phpunit, rsync

Before pushing to git, I'd like to run all feature and unit tests locally.  But doing so takes 15 minutes (we have a lot of tests).

While waiting, I'd like to switch branches and work on something else. But of course I cant do this, because that could potentially change the tests (and the code that is being tested) in current test run.

Instead, before switching branches, I'd like to run an rsync command to a different folder, have PHPStorm load that project in a new PHPStorm Instance, and run my tests on the branch that was just rsynced.  Then I can move onto switching branches, while I wait till the other PHPStorm instance to finish the tests.

the problem is however,is that our dev setup is a docker instance.
When I try to do docker-compose up, I get an error message:

```
Error response from daemon: 2 matches found based on name: network project_test_default is ambiguous
```

Any ideas how I can get another group of containers up so I can switch branches and code while I am waiting for local testing to complete?

Comment: what you truly want, is a CI system like CircleCI or githube actions or Bitbucket pipelines (or anything similar) to process your push to git and run the actions to test the code. You need to add CI into your pipeline/workflow

Comment: we have this on gitHub, but its expensive. What I'd like to do is have a local server to do unit testing before I push to github, may just use another computer

Comment: Yeah, it can get quite expensive, but using `rsync` or anything similar is going to be a pain for you... I used to work in a company where we had 2k tests, and it took between 13 and 20 minutes... CircleCI, 25$ a month, it is an absolute resonable price (and we didn't use all the monthly credit so we carried over/saved credits)... Just by experience, if you need a super complex/over engineered solution, it means the project has huge red flags that must be solved. I understand if that is not your issue but someone elses, but still, 25$ a month should do it for any small company